Angular title case all words except few
I'm facing an issue I have an object
{
    "Draft": 19,
    "Process Model QA review in progress": 22,
    "Process Model QA Rejected": 17,
    "Process Model QA Approved": 13,
    "Process Owner review in progress": 28,
    "Approved": 22,
    "Opt-out": 3,
    "Process Owner Rejected": 4,
    "Process Owner Approved": 10,
    "Soln. Architect review in progress": 4,
    "Soln. Architect Rejected": 4,
    "Cancelled": 10
}

constructor(@Self() private titleCasePipe: TitleCasePipe)

 Object.entries(obj).map(elem => {
    arr.push({'id': elem[0], 'name': this.titleCasePipe.transform(elem[0]) + " (" + elem[1] + ")"})
 })
 
 console.log(arr)

I need to capitalize the first letter of all words of object keys. Hence, I used titleCase pipe to achieve it but it also capitalized QA to Qa - (Process Model Qa Review In Progress).
I'm not sure if there is any way to skip QA and capitalize others?
OR
Since obj data arrives from HTTP API, I can use map operator to capitalize it?

The code for titlecase is very straight forward, with no customizations!
// #docregion
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'titlecase', standalone: true, pure: true })
/** Transform to Title Case: uppercase the first letter of the words in a string. */
export class TitleCasePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(input: string): string {
    return input.length === 0
      ? ''
      : input.replace(/\w\S*/g, (txt) => txt[0].toUpperCase() + txt.slice(1).toLowerCase());
  }
}

Just go for post transformation, do a regex replace of the whitelisted keywords!
Working example below!
import { CommonModule, TitleCasePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, Self } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  providers: [TitleCasePipe],
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from {{ name }}!</h1>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://angular.dev/overview">
      Learn more about Angular
    </a>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';

  constructor(@Self() private titleCasePipe: TitleCasePipe) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const obj = {
      Draft: 19,
      'Process Model QA review in progress': 22,
      'Process Model QA Rejected': 17,
      'Process Model QA Approved': 13,
      'Process Owner review in progress': 28,
      Approved: 22,
      'Opt-out': 3,
      'Process Owner Rejected': 4,
      'Process Owner Approved': 10,
      'Soln. Architect review in progress': 4,
      'Soln. Architect Rejected': 4,
      Cancelled: 10,
    };

    const arr: any = [];
    Object.entries(obj).map((elem) => {
      arr.push({
        id: elem[0],
        name: this.safeTransform(elem[0]) + ' (' + elem[1] + ')',
      });
    });

    console.log(arr);
  }

  safeTransform(elem: any) {
    let output = this.titleCasePipe.transform(elem);
    // whitelist
    ['QA'].forEach((regexKey) => {
      var re = new RegExp(regexKey, 'gi');
      output = output.replace(re, regexKey);
    });
    return output;
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

Opt-out': 3, is skipped from transformation

@Urvashi its working fine for me stackblitz

['QA', 'Out'] - made this changes in order to work. Thanks

As you can see in the source code here, the title case pipe is quite dumb and for each word, takes the first letter and makes it uppercase while the rest of the word is made lowercase.
What you can do though is take insipration from that code, either by creating your own custom pipe or by adding your own regex that will transform 'Qa' back into 'QA'.
The code can be input.replace(/Qa\s/g, (txt) => "QA ");
